# Anyone knows of an OpenSource Collaborative Translation app?

Tags: web-applications, open-source, translation, crowdsourcing, collaborative

like the one Facebook used to localize its site?

Comment: could you use the google translate api?

Comment: you can always... always write your own...

Answer (score 16):

Hosting for Open Source projects is usually free, but quite expensive for commercial projects on most platforms.

I have limited my answers to projects, which provide their software as Open Source.

- Pootle - Python - http://pootle.translatehouse.org/ - Hosting: NA
- ReGlot, a fork of GlotPress - PHP - https://github.com/ReGlot/ReGlot / Hosting: https://translate.foe-services.de 18 USD per year per 500 strings
- Launchpad - PHP - http://launchpad.net Hosting: https://launchpad.net/+tour/join-launchpad#commercial 250 USD per year per project
- Transifex - Python - https://github.com/transifex/transifex/ - Hosting: transifex.com 19 USD per month per 15000 words
- Zanata - Java - http://zanata.org - Hosting: NA
- Weblate - Python - http://weblate.org/ - Hosting: http://weblate.org/en/hosting/

Answer (score 1):

Commercial Product:

[Transifex](http://transifex.org/)
is a modern localization workflow and crowdsourcing platform, suited for software and dynamic content translation.

They also have a Community Edition (open source) which is located at [transifex.org](http://transifex.org) or https://github.com/transifex/transifex/

Comment: It should be noted that the open-source edition is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that [Lingumania](http://lingumania.com/) is open source, but it does it in a very similar fashion like the one Facebook used.